# Ranking/polling field or webform module

Tags: webforms, entities, polls

I am trying to find a field (ideally, for use with Entity Forms), or a webform module that allows me to poll users.

I have found several modules like "Fivestar" and others that do basic polling, but I want to be able to do relative/comparative ranking.  Essentially I want to be able to give users a list of options (say A, B, C), and allow them to rank in order (1, 2, 3) by their opinions.  Ideally this could be done via a draggable table.

For what it is worth, it appears to be on the roadmap for the pollfield module (https://drupal.org/project/pollfield), but that module doesn't appear to be supported.

Any suggestions or leads would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use a field for polling, I would recommend using a polling entity created by a module specific to polls. There is a core poll module.

There are also many contributed modules, the choice would depend on your use case: Advanced Poll, Poll Improved, Poll Extras -- and Poll Blocks provide a block for every core poll.

Then add some theming to make the selections draggable. I have created front-end doodads that populate a hidden element on the page - even an entire node body - so you could register the selections that way if you cannot theme the actual poll items.

You may need to use panels/views/context or template file to add the poll to your page.

My favorite place to search for Drupal contributted modules is http://drupalmodules.com/search/node/poll

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a webform instead of an entity form, there's a module for that!  Check out https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_draggable_list