# rating of multiple items

Tags: rating

I need to create a rating entry on a profile that needs to have 5 items that the user can rate in order from 1 to 5 (most to least important).  Does anyone know of a module that can do this or can point me in the right way to make my own (I've never done that before)

Thanks!

Comment: What about creating one field for each as integer from 1 to 5?

Comment: Would there be a way to prevent them from entering the same number twice?  Each entry should be a unique number

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on books, tools, modules, themes, distributions, tutorials, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to implement this for a Drupal 7 site, you could:

1. enable webforms on the "profile" content type
2. install/enable https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_draggable_list
3. setup a webform attached to every profile with the draggable list.

Other Drupal 6 & 7 options for this are noted in this prior thread:
[Ranking/polling field or webform module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100642/ranking-polling-field-or-webform-module)

For Drupal 8, you could potentially do a similar setup as the webform_draggable_list option.

Comment: Oh I like this, I hadn't seen this module.  I'll take a closer look this weekend.  I'll give you the check if it does :)

Comment: How do I enable webforms on Profile2 profiles?